# cocoa touch : login view / table view / details view

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know what is the best strategy in terms of view/viewcontroller for the following scenario for an IPad App. I have 4 views :

View #1 = Login (username/password)

View #2 = List (table) of appointments

View #3 = Appointment details (+ back button to return to View #2)

View #4 = Editable view to add notes to an appointment

I was starting with a UITableViewController but it seems that it doesn't really fit my needs because the navigation is not always table oriented.

What would be the strategy in this case? A custom view controller? any examples out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect use case for an `UISplitViewController`.